# Add attributed text hides UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

I'm trying to add a strikethrough to some of my labels.
My project supports 32 and 64 bit.
Everything works great on iOS 8, but on iOS 7 on iPhone 5c the label just disappear.
Here's my code:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *throughLineAttributeString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:label.text];
    [throughLineAttributeString addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName
                                       value:@1
                                       range:NSMakeRange(0, [throughLineAttributeString length])];
label.attributedText = throughLineAttributeString;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: add label.layer.borderWidth = 3; and check, is it gone away or it just shows nothing

Comment: Yes the label is still there with the same frame. Seems like just the text is missing.

Comment: ok, set label.layer.masksToBounds = NO, and check the text position

Comment: with this line the text will be rendered outside of labels frame to

Comment: I don't see any text anywhere

Comment: is it hapend only on IPhone 5C or on any device with IOS 7?

Comment: Only on iPhone 5C with iOS7 with specific labels (for other labels it works)

Comment: try programatically add text color

Comment: As far as I rememeber iOS 7 had issues with underlined texts, I had to render it manually once. There are nice components like THLabel that take care of this for you. Besides, you might like to set color for your text because it can be simply invisible and match your background.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *throughLineAttributeString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:label.text];
```

to:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *throughLineAttributeString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:label.attributedText];
```

Comment: The label doesn't have an attributedText at this point. It has only text.